# WebDriver SelectElement get selected value

Tags: testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

```
var test = SelectElement([TheIWebElemement]);
Assert.AreEqual("55", test.SelectedOption.Text);
```

Based on the above snippet, does anyone know how to get the selected value in the dropdown. I am opening a form in edit mode, so I know the value I expect the selected option to have. I do not want the text, I want the value behind the option as the text I don't care about. 
From my inspecting, all I can seem to get at is the text of the option.

Comment: Does it work when you get the text in the option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedOption` that is returned is simply the `IWebElement` representing that option.

Therefore, your question becomes 'how do I get the value of an `option` element?'. Since the `SelectElement` is kind and has given you the `IWebElement` for free, you can simply do:

```
var selectedValue = test.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value");
Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(selectedValue);
Assert.AreEqual("the value", selectedValue);
```